# Android Chip: How to change text vertical padding?

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android, android-chips

Is there a way to change chip text vertical padding? I dig into the api and it looks like we can only change startPadding and endPadding using :

```
app:chipStartPadding
app:chipEndPadding
app:textStartPadding
app:textEndPadding
```

so how can we do things like changing chipTopPadding or textTopPadding?

Answer (score 7):

You can only reduce the height of the `Chip` using the **`chipMinHeight`** attribute:

```
    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        app:chipMinHeight="24dp"
        .../>
```

The `layout_height` parameter is not enough since the minHeight is based on `chipMinHeight`.
Here the difference with a standard `Chip`:

[image]

Also if you want to reduce the touch target size using the **`chipMinTouchTargetSize`** attribute:

```
        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            app:chipMinHeight="24dp"
            app:chipMinTouchTargetSize="24dp"
```

Here you can check the difference in design mode:

[image]

Comment: Thx for the answer, are those two attributes should be used on the same time?

Comment: Also I wonder what's the difference between chipMinHeight and layout_height, can i just set chip height to 24dp?

Answer (score 0):

before: [image]
after: [image]

```
app:textEndPadding="0dp"
app:chipEndPadding="0dp"
```